# variable defined in header file shared?

Tags: c, header-files

In header file "foo.h", there is the following statement,

```
int foo;
```

In source file "a.c" and "b.c", the header file is included.

```
#include "foo.h"
```

Are there two independent foo's in two places or there is only one foo shared across "a.c" and "b.c"? I see this happens in a shared piece of code from others. Thanks in advance if you can understand this.

Answer (score 2):

You will get an error by defining an external object multiple times.

Use `extern int foo;` in the header file and `int foo;` in exactly one `.c` file.

The `extern` specifier (if there is no initializer) at file-scope declares without defining.

Comment: This is not totally correct. I am now refactoring code and that's exactly what it is doing. No error.

Comment: @UmNyobe The fact you don't get an error does not mean it is correct. C says multiple object definition is undefined behavior (see C99, 6.9p5): the implementation does not have to trigger an error message but the program is still an erroneous C program. Now this is also a common C extension (common enough to be list in C99 J.5 extensions).

Comment: It thinks it fits the case of a tentative definition. Which means the linker sees several `int foo;` and decide that all these definitions are the one of the same object. I looked inside the .o and executable with an elf reader to get confirmation.

Comment: @UmNyobe It wouldn't be a problem if the multiple `int foo;` were in a same `.c` file: you would have multiple tentative definitions which is valid. But here there are multiple `int foo;` in *different* `.c` file: this means at the end of every source file, all tentative definitions cause a definition to be created and you'll end up with multiple object definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor just substitutes the `#include "foo.h"` with the contents of `foo.h`.

It's entirely equivalent to `a.c` and `b.c` containing both `int foo;`